# How to validate objects in Array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object

```
x = [{id: 1, status: false}, {id: 2, status: false}, {id: 3, status: false}]
```

I want to validate and call a method when all the status is true.

Need help on validating each object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const allTrue  = x.every(obj => obj.status === true)
if(allTrue){
 // call your method
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.prototype.every for this
The every() method tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a Boolean value.

```
const valid = x.every(item => item.status === true)
if (valid){
    // CALL THE METHOD YOU WANT 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
   const isAllStatusesTrue = x.every(item => item.status === true);

   if (isAllStatusesTrue) {
       // Some actions
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing a validation function using Array's filter function:

```
const isValid = objects => {
    return objects.filter(el => !el.status).length === 0;
}


// Use your const x:
console.log(isValid(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

here example:

```
x = [{id: 1, status: false}, {id: 2, status: false}, {id: 3, status: false}];

function validateStatus(arr){
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(!arr[i].status){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

console.log(validateStatus(x));
```